# Invalid scopes error message, when login from developer account in facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook

My app is live on facebook for more than a year now. Recently i have a new requirement to get user's gender, location and other information when user logs in through facebook.

My email address is added on the app as an administrator. So it should work seamlessly when i login into facebook from my developer account, but instead i am getting following error message.

> Invalid scopes: user_birthday, user_hometown, user_likes, user_gender,
>   user_location

Following is my code.

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(),Arrays.asList(
                            "email", "public_profile", "user_birthday", "user_gender", "user_age_range",
                            "user_hometown", "user_likes", "user_location"));
```

**Facebook SDK:**

```
com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.41.0
```

Comment: Does Facebook change how their scopes are named now?

Comment: @AvivLo : I don't think so.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Comment: Not all permissions _can_ be asked for any more, when the app is in live mode, and the permission in question has not been approved in review yet.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe: can you please also share any documentation link, where this is mentioned.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review has a note on top, _“If you switch your app to Live mode before you have been approved, you will lose access to all data including that of your app, test users, test pages, and app developers and app admins.”_ I don’t know if it is documented anywhere else in a more broad way.